# Sort Woocommerce featured products first with ascending price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Like the title suggests, I want to change the default ordering of the woocommerce shop page to display the featured products first and on ascending order. I managed to display the featured products first but the orderby $args in function 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' dont work for the featured products.

```
//add new sorting option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['recommended'] = __('Ταξινόμηση: Προεπιλογή', 'woocommerce');
    return $sortby;
}

//set default sorting for new option
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'recommended' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_price';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    }
    return $args;
}

//adjust order to allow for featured posts
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'show_featured_products_orderby',10,2);
function show_featured_products_orderby($order_by, $query){
  global  $wpdb ;
  if( (!is_admin()) ){
    $orderby_value = ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( (string) $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) ) );
    $orderby_value_array = explode( '-', $orderby_value );
    $orderby = esc_attr( $orderby_value_array[0] );
    $order = ( !empty($orderby_value_array[1]) ? $orderby_value_array[1] : 'ASC' );
    $feture_product_id = wc_get_featured_product_ids();
    //only apply to recommended sorting option
    if ( $orderby == "recommended" && is_array( $feture_product_id ) && !empty($feture_product_id) ) {
      if ( empty($order_by) ) {
        $order_by = "FIELD(" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID,'" . implode( "','", $feture_product_id ) . "') DESC ";
      } else {
        $order_by = "FIELD(" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID,'" . implode( "','", $feture_product_id ) . "') DESC, " . $order_by;
      }
    }  
  }
  return $order_by;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the post. Do you want to show non-featured products or not? If yes, should the featured products be placed before the non-featured, correct? Should also the non-featured products be sorted by price?

Comment: Hello, the code above displays the featured products before every other product. Im ok on that. When i try to sort Everything by price tho. Only the non featured products are sorting, something i don't want. I want everything, including the featured products to be sorted.